# Undefined method when trying to pass through id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to pass a project ID from its show page to an employee_projects form where I can display the projects name. The error I'm getting is

```
undefined local variable or method `project_id' for #<EmployeeProjectsController:0xb8bdd58>.
```

employee_project controller:

```
# GET /employee_projects/new
  def new
    puts params[project_id]
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    session[:project_id] = @project.id
    @employee_project = EmployeeProject.new 
  end
```

employee_projects form

```
  Assign worker for this project <%= project.projectName%><br>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :employee_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :employee_id, Employee.all, :id, :empLastName, :prompt => "Select worker" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Projects show

```
<%= button_to "Assign!", new_employee_project_path(project_id: @project.id) , class: "btn btn-primary", :method => :get %>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: please check wether you are getting @project.id at the show. page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller try changing `puts params[project_id]` to `puts params[:project_id]`.

`params` is a `Hash` so you must refer to its keys with symbols, that is `:project_id`. `project_id` is just a variable that has no value assigned to it, hence the error `undefined local variable or method 'project_id' for #`.

**UPDATE** (`"Couldn't find Project with 'id'="` fix)

The button in projects' `show` view is not sending the parameter `project_id` even though you are passing it to the `new_employee_project_path` helper (check your *url* string and you will see it ending at `?` with no parameters). To fix it, i recommend using a regular `form` instead of `button_to` helper.

So, instead of this line:

```
<%= button_to "Assign!", new_employee_project_path(project_id: @project.id) , class: "btn btn-primary", :method => :get %>
```

Try using this `form`:

```
<form action="<%= new_employee_project_path %>" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="<%= @project.id %>">
  <input type="submit" value="Assign!" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Comment: Still not working, getting "Couldn't find Project with 'id'=" error now.

Comment: Most likely is that `@project` has no value, can you share the `show` action for `employee_project_controller.rb`?

Comment: My show method in the employee_project_controller is just an empty method? On my show page I can call all values from the project using @ project tho such as @ project.projectName and that works fine on the show page

Comment: The problem seems to be in the `button_to` helper, check the update on the answer.